# Critical Error Linting URL: An internal error occurred while linting the URL

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I tried to create a post (using a blogger URL) in the Facebook Power Editor. 
Result:

> Error creating posts. Please retry later. You can also go to your Page and post from there. (OAuthException) (#1500) The url you supplied is invalid

Then tried to install Facebook's Open Graph tags into Blogger to see of that would fix the problem.

To test the OG tags I used Open Graph Object Debugger. 
Here are the results:

> Critical Errors That Must Be Fixed, Error Linting URL, An internal error occurred while linting the URL.

How do I fix the invalid URL and the Critical: Error Linting URL?

I am not tech savy so this issue is way over my head but I would like to get it fixed. Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Can you share the URL you're testing with the debugger tool?

Answer (score 5):

I had a problem like this with the og:image pointing to an image hosted on Rackspace.  The URL was something crazy like
http://1234567890abcdef1234-1234567890abcdef123456780123412b.r23.cf5.rackcdn.com

I think the Facebook linter was seeing this as spam, because if I actually embedded the image in my app/assets it worked fine, so it wasn't the image that was the problem.

The solution was to set up a CNAME on my hosting provider that pointed to the hideously long Rackspace URL, e.g.

> CNAME  Value
>
> images  http://1234567890abcdef1234-1234567890abcdef123456780123412b.r23.cf5.rackcdn.com

Then I changed the og:image meta tag to be
meta property="og:image" content="http://images.mydomain.com/relative_rackspace_imagepath.jpg"

Comment: I could kiss you right now mdenomy! A quick note on this: I had to turn on the static web hosting for my media CDN container for this to work. Just making a CNAME wasn't enough.

Comment: This worked perfect for me too.  Amazing find @mdenomy

Comment: @mdenomy, It will takes how much time to display image make changes?

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to contribute a little data point here as this is currently the top google result for this error and there is little useful info out there.

In my case, the page was a post on a wordpress blog that happened to begin with a twitter post embed, and the twitter post happened to contain an url.  My og tag plugin grabbed the embed and managed to place the url along with a little other cruft in og:description, and once I cleaned that up manually the error disappeared.

I think the lesson is that when this happens take a look at your og tags for the page for ANYTHING unusual.  That's the place to start.

Answer (score 2):

Happened to me once my og:image pointed to this url:
http://xxxxxxx.appspot.com.storage.googleapis.com/IsraelFlag.jpg

I just changed it to:
http://storage.googleapis.com/xxxxxxx.appspot.com/IsraelFlag.jpg
and it works

probably very poor software parses the html

Comment: @MosheShaham, It will take how much time to display image make changes?

Answer (score 1):

I spent hours trying to debug why this was happening for our site.  It turns out it was because of the og:locale:alternate meta tags we had.

```
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="cs_CZ" />
<meta property="og:locale:alternate" content="de_DE" />
...
```

When Facebook sees this in your tags they subsequently hit your og:url with '?fb_locale=[lang]' where [lang] is each of your alternates.  There is one request per alternate.  In our case, we had code that was returning back a 302 on that request.  As a result, the Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger kept saying "Error parsing input URL"

Once I fixed the responses to the alternate requests to actually return internationalized content, the issue was fixed.