# Facebook share for my site resulting in blank page

Tags: php, facebook, socialshare

When I try to share any link on my site with facebook sharer.php, I get a blank page

I want to share

`http://sportmenow.com/bar.php?id=10`

with

`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fsportmenow.com%2Fbar.php%3Fid%3D10`

But this sends me to a blank page (firefox and chrome)

as does simply

`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=sportmenow.com`

Is this because of some issue with the site hosting? It is accessible to the web...

Comment: Would the downvoter care to share their critique?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but stop using sharer.php, it's been deprecated for like a decade. You should be using the feed/share dialogs. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog

Comment: @ceejayoz Really? Don't see anything to that effect in the [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button) . Also http://stackoverflow.com/a/20987387/1520364

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I needed to add facebooks OG tags. I guess this is a relatively new requirement? I inherited this site recently, so I was not present when it was implemented first, but I hear it was working.

How did I infer this

Step 1 - I have just discovered the Facebook debugger

[this page](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=sportmenow.com) suggests that there is something wrong with the formating of my html or something in that area, and it is possible that the critical error is the one causing this issue.

There is also [wave.com](http://wave.webaim.org/report#/sportmenow.com) which also performs such checks, but not sure if they are the same errors.

Step 2- [Critical Error Linting URL: An internal error occurred while linting the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169025/critical-error-linting-url-an-internal-error-occurred-while-linting-the-url) and others kept suggesting the og tags which led me to try it out. Adding a `og:image` tag fixed it.